# Would adding a small dash of whisky when bottling kill secondary fermentation?

Tags: secondary-fermentation

I assume that secondary fermentation's upper limit is set by some balance between sugars remaining and alcohol content, is that fair to say?

Would giving just a dash of flavour potentially wreck the secondary fermentation process? I am planning on bottling and throwing in a sucrose pellet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most brewers yeast has a alcohol tolerance of at least 10%, so if your beer was around or under 10% then carbonation and conditioning will continue as normal.

If your beer is pushing that limit check the tolerance of the yeast you used - some yeasts have a much higher alcohol tolerance, meaning you'll still be fine.

Comment: Much obliged to both answers, I googled around and 10% looks to be the reasonable tolerable limit for my yeast. I might test a very small number on this run, and if it works, try again later. I will try a rough dilution calculation before bottling, and try an upper and a low limit and mark my bottles.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there's no reason it should.  I make a Bourbon Vanilla Imperial Porter that gets 375 ml. of bourbon added at bottling.  It's strong beer even before the bourbon, and there has never been a problem carbonating it.  Unless adding the liquor pushed the beer over 12+% ABV, you should have no problem.

Comment: Denny, is that 375ml per 5 gal batch?  Sounds awesome.

Comment: Yes it is.  Here's the recipe...http://wiki.homebrewersassociation.org/BourbonVanillaImperialPorter

Comment: That sounds great. We're getting ready to go all-grain using your batch sparge method and will add this to our want to brew list!